# Flutter Hive getting double of an item in a list after app restart

Tags: flutter, hive, flutter-listview

I am building a simple budgeting app in flutter and I am using Hive for local data storage. I have a list of weeks, that gets loaded from a hive box when the app starts:

```
class WeekList extends ChangeNotifier {
  WeekList() {
    int boxLength = box.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < boxLength; i++) {
      listOfWeeks.add(box.getAt(i));
    }
  }
```

The problem I am seeing is if I start a new week, and then quickly restart the app it loads with two of the last week. Adding a new week runs this code:

```
  void addWeek({
    required double budget,
  }) {
    Week newWeek = Week(
      budget: budget,
    );

    listOfWeeks.add(newWeek);
    box.add(newWeek);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The odd part is if I add a new week, and edit a value in the week then when I restart the app it does not create double of the last week on load...

Updating a value in the week looks like this:

```
  //updateSundayValue
  void updateSunday(
      {required double newValue, required int index, required Week week}) {
    listOfWeeks[index].sunday = twoDecimalPlaces(newValue, 2);
    listOfWeeks[index].sundayDisplayValue =
        twoDecimalPlaces(newValue, 2).toString();
    box.putAt(index, week);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

its odd to me that it will repeat the last week added to the list on load if I dont edit the new week I just added....

**Update 1: More troubleshooting**

I am conducting some more troubleshooting, by adding a bunch of print statements to the code before and after the add week.

In this code below I check my hive box and load all its contents into a list of weeks and print out the value for sunday.

I then run the `addWeek()` function and afterwards I reload all the contents from the hive box into another list of weeks and out put it.

Before the save I have two weeks, whos sunday values are 1 and 2.

I then `addWeek()` which should default to a sunday value of 0. But when I see the output of the print statement it somehow copes the week before it and prints out 1 and 2 and 2 and I expect it to be 1 and 2 and 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use box.put() instead of box.add(), box.add() will keep adding the data and create a list. use box.put(key,'Your string');
it will work

Comment: thats what I want through a list of weeks. And I need it to grow each time you add a new week.

Comment: I did try using put but ran into the same issue..